# How to play only 1 sound by AudioToolBox?

Tags: ios, audio, audiotoolbox

I want to make a music app, it has a few buttons to play sounds.

For example: Sound1 is a 10 senconds sound. Sound2 is a 10 seconds sound, too.

When I play Sound1, after 3 seconds I start to play Sound2.

But Sound1 is not stopped when I play Sound2, their sounds are mixed together.

I don't want to mix them together, I want to play Sound2, then Sound1 should be stopped, only the last sound should be playing.

How can I do it with Audio ToolBox?

This is my button code:

```
- (IBAction)btn1:(id)sender {
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();

    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"sound1",CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL);

    UInt32 sound1;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &sound1);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(sound1);
}

- (IBAction)btn2:(id)sender {
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();

    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"sound2",CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL);

    UInt32 sound1;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &sound1);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(sound1);
}
```